# When you are using Xcode to make an iPhone app, how do you change the app's icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons

When you are using Xcode to make an iPhone app, how do you change the app's icon? Right now my icon for my app is just plain white.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a 57x57 PNG file and import it into your project bundle. Then open the .plist file that is included in your project and edit the value for the key "Icon File" to match the name of the icon you provided (`CFBundleIconFile` is the actual key, but the Xcode editor will display the nicer name for you).

Comment: Anytime. You might want to look over Apple's developer documentation at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/ - they have a wealth of information about working with Xcode and deploying iPhone applications.

Answer (score 24):

In Xcode 4, you can go to your app's **Summary** page and there is a section called **App Icons**. Then just drag and drop an image into one of the "drop zones". It just works! :D

Answer (score 15):

If you don't specify the icon in the Info.plist file, then Xcode assumes that a file named "icon.png" in your resources folder is the icon for the application.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode4 go to your applications summary section by selecting target project there you see section with name app icons.select your icon image of size 57x57.just do it it will work

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5 you can do it very simply:
1) go to images.xcassets
2) click on AppIcon
3) select Show Overview instead of Slicing
4) drag and drop the appropriate icon sizes onto the icon slots
5) rebuild - and you are good to go.